# Migrated to jersey 2.x and now I get servlet container exception

Tags: java, maven, servlets, web.xml, jersey-2.0

So I'm building a small rest api with java using Jersey 2.23.2. I have run into a problem however, I am not able to specify the servlet in the web.xml file properly. This is how my files look like:

*pom.xml*

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.23.2</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

*web.xml*

```
...
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>api-mashup-api.API</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

*API.java*

```
package api;
    @Path("/v1")
    public class API {
    private Controller controller;

    public API(){
        controller = new Controller();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String print1() {
        return "Please specify what resource you need.";
    }

    /**
     * Prints to the screen if we are in /v1/foo
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @GET
    @Path("/foobar")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String print2() {
        return "Please specify what resource you need.";
    }
}
```

My project folder structure looks like this:

```
api-mashup-api/Java Resources/src/api/API.java
```

I used Jersey 1.x before and then I migrated to 2.x and now I'm not sure what to put into the params of the servlet in web.xml. When I try to run the API.java on my tomcat server I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet [WebService] in web application [/api-mashup-api] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
```

I can reach my index.html just fine though, so the server works, but not the API part. Not sure what to do here. Obviously something is wrong with the servlet part.

EDIT-Things I have tried:

- Added  API.java to the param-valye in the web.xml
- Looked at [Basic full configuration for Jersey on Tomcat in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778893/basic-full-configuration-for-jersey-on-tomcat-in-eclipse/37784074#37784074)
  And implemented the solution. Now when running the api, the server won't crash, but I can't find any resource with http://localhost:8080/api-mashup-api/v1 for example.

  - Removed scope tag from the glassfish servlet container dependency.

Comment: Can you try <param-value>api</param-value> ? Also, add the API.java case this doesn't work.

Comment: Tried both, they gave me the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I mean add the API.java class to the post.

Comment: Tried that aswell. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: take a look at that post and this one doesn't need web.xml. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778893/basic-full-configuration-for-jersey-on-tomcat-in-eclipse/37784074#37784074

Comment: Tried it out, my server won't throw any exceptions but I can't manage to reach any resource with URL. I tried http://localhost:8080/api-mashup-api/v1 for example, but that does not work.

Comment: what server are you using ?

Comment: Tomcat 8.55. I run it straight from Eclipse.

Comment: okay remove scope tag for the jersey servlet dependency in the pom.xml and try again.

Comment: I tried it, didn't seem to make any difference. :(

Comment: add all the changes you tried so far to the question.

Comment: also add the API.java class to the question.

Comment: I  have added it now.

Comment: please change to <param-value>api</param-value> as it should match the package name of your class. I cant think of any other issues.

Comment: That...actually fixed it! I'm sure I tried that before though.... Anyhow, a big thank you!

Comment: Though now a new problem arised. Before I had a method, named getPosts that retrieved twitter and facebook posts&tweets and returned in JSON format which worked fine. Now this method returns a json object on the form {"escapeForwardSlashAlways":true} not sure what happend here.

Answer (score 0):

I've had and fixed this error many times. It's basically always a dependency issue.

Here are the steps to fix it:

1. Make sure you're using the most recent version of all packages (i.e. 2.23.2 of glassfish) and servers, updating your POM accordingly. This is very important for your case since you're using the new version of Jersey.
2. Refresh your project
3. Use the Maven menu to clean and build
4. Use the Maven menu to refresh (this is different from the project refresh)

Don't skip steps or assume that if you've done some of them here and there in the past that it's the same as doing them one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Probably issue with servlet container "jersey-container-servlet-core" is for servlet 2.x containers, try changing to

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
          <version>2.23.2</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```